# Template value before typename

Tags: c++, templates

I have following simplified example code where I attempt to figure out whether given value is the maximum value of enum of it's type.

```cpp
enum class MyEnum : unsigned char {
    VALUE,
    OTHER_VALUE,
    _LAST
};

template<typename T, T _L>
bool is_not_last(T value) {
    return value < _L;
}

int main()
{
    is_not_last<MyEnum, MyEnum::_LAST>(MyEnum::OTHER_VALUE);

    return 0;
}
```

How can I format template so I can call `is_not_last` without specifying type first.

Desired outcome:
`is_not_last<MyEnum::_LAST>(MyEnum::OTHER_VALUE);`

Following declarations didn't work:

```
template<T _L>
bool is_not_last(T value); // Doesn't have typename specified

template<typename T _L>
bool is_not_last(T value); // Invalid syntax
```

I feel like compiler should be able to deduce type from `MyEnum::_LAST` but I haven't been able to figure that out.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Identifiers beginning with underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation. Don't use them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since C++17, you might do

```
template <auto L>
bool is_not_last(decltype(L) value) {
    return value < L;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/TnMv1s3qM)